# Group by dataframe support needed

Tags: python, attributes

```
Year Month Product startTime Endtime 
1111   JAN  A       11 PM   12 am
2222   feb   B       6 AM   6.30 PM
3333   mAR   C       4 PM   4.30 PM


I have a dataframe as above and need graphs grouping by Year ,month or product

I have been getting below error ,can someone advise .
```

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [5], line 1
----> 1 df=df.groupby ([dates.dt.year]).agg(overall= ('Product' , 'sum'))

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'groupby'

```
Thanks in advance
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [5], line 1
----> 1 df=df.groupby ([dates.dt.year]).agg(overall= ('Product' , 'sum'))

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

Comment: what is **dates** in groupby ? Also it seems df is not a dataframe.

Comment: Apologies i used an other column and pasted -my original request is from the above data which i read from excel needs to be grouped either by year ,product or MOnth - how do i achieve that ?